# How to reset location_provider_allowed

Tags: settings, 7.0-nougat, gps, tasker, shell

as the first, my environment:

Samsung S7, LineageOS 14.1, which is Android 7.2.1.

I'm using tasker to set GPS On and Off in this way:

GPS On:

```
settings put secure location_providers_allowed +gps,network,wifi
```

GPS Off:

```
settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps,network,wifi
```

Both script are running as root.

Somethink happend (maybe during I tested this scripts) and now I can't switch my GPS Off (in Settings menu), and when I list my settings in this way:

```
settings list secure
```

I can see this:

```
  location_providers_allowed=wifi,wifi,+network,+wifi,+network,+wifi,+network,...+wifi,network,network
```

It is very long line with cyclic contents.

Please, is there a way to reset this setting (perhaps another than factory reset of phone)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change it to blank by executing

```
settings put secure location_providers_allowed ' '
```

If that doesn't work, directly modify the file *settings_secure.xml* located at */data/system/users/0/*. Look for the line containing *location_providers_allowed* and edit the value for it.